# Can I use telegram API methods for Telegram Bot?

Tags: laravel, telegram, telegram-bot, lumen, php-telegram-bot

can I use some methods from here - [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/methods) for my Telegram Bot. I am asking because I need in a methods which no present in Telegram Bot Api. If yes, please write How I can to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Those methods are for Telegram Clients, not for bots. Bots can only use the methods listed [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods).

Answer (score 1):

As the other contributor has already answered, you can't normally use Telegram API inside bots.
But you can actually leverage some libraries like ([MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto) (php), [Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/) (python), [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/) (python), etc...) to create a userbot instance behind the scene and the bot can delegate the tasks that requires Telegram API to the userbot in the background.